# get cellid in j2me

Tags: java-me, cellid

I am using this code to get cell id from my sony erricson p990 cellphone but it set cellID value to "no property".

> Blockquote

```
        String cellID = System.getProperty("com.sonyericsson.net.cellid");
        if(cellID == null)
            cellID = System.getProperty("CellID");

        if(cellID == null)
            cellID = "no property";
```

> Blockquote

How can I solve this problem? Is signing the program solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

the above code is working, by the way you should try http://www.easywms.com/easywms/?q=en/node/3589